# remove index when writing to s3

Tags: csv, dataframe, amazon-s3, indexing

When trying to write a *DF* to a *CSV* in *S3* the following code works. However there is still the index column when i open the file in *S3* after i have run the code. The code i have used is:

```
def write_to_csv():
    bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(None).encode()
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    with fs.open('s3://filepath', 'wb', index = False) as f:
        f.write(bytes_to_write)
    print ('Wrote Dataframe To CSV ...')

write_to_csv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Removed the index set to false from the file system open to the dataframe to csv

```
def write_to_csv():
    bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(index = False).encode()
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
    with fs.open('s3://filepath', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(bytes_to_write)
    print ('Wrote Dataframe To CSV ...')

write_to_csv()
```